# Populate date cells based on one cell's value?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the ability for the user to enter a year (e.g. "2013") in cell D1 and press a button that fires off a macro.  This macro will automatically assign a function to cells D2-O2 (one cell for each month in the year) that converts these cells to actual date types.

For instance, cell D2's value would be `=DATE(2013, 1, 1)`, signifying that this cell represents January 1st of 2013.  Similarly, cell E2's value would be `=DATE(2013, 2, 1)`, F2's value would be `=DATE(2013, 3, 1)`, etc.

The following is my pseudo code, could you please help me convert this to actual VBA?

```
var myYear = the value of cell D1
cell D2 value is =DATE(2013,1,1)
cell E2 value is =DATE(2013,2,1)
cell F2 value is =DATE(2013,3,1)
cell G2 value is =DATE(2013,4,1)
cell H2 value is =DATE(2013,5,1)
cell I2 value is =DATE(2013,6,1)
cell J2 value is =DATE(2013,7,1)
cell K2 value is =DATE(2013,8,1)
cell L2 value is =DATE(2013,9,1)
cell M2 value is =DATE(2013,10,1)
cell N2 value is =DATE(2013,11,1)
cell O2 value is =DATE(2013,12,1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try recording a macro and then modifying it to suit your needs?

Comment: I guess I never thought of that.  I don't work with Excel much.  Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Do you want the dates to be a value or a formula?  So if the user runs the macro and THEN changes the year in D1, should the cells update to reflect the changed year, or should they stay the same?

Comment: I could have given you the code but I am sure it is more fun discovering it yourself ;) BTW I feel that you have a C# background? In VBA, `Dim myYear1 As String` goes in 1 line and `myYear1=Range(D1).Value` goes in another unlike vb.net or C#. Also for concatenation we use "&" instead of "+" in VBA :)

Comment: @PaulStock It would be ideal if the dates changed after the cell update.  That would prevent user error (e.g. forgetting to click the macro button).  Is this possible?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks!  Yes, I actually do have a background in C# and C++, so some of my coding tendencies tend to get mixed up.  I think I rely on Visual Studio's Intellisense too much, because some VBA is confusing to me.  Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FillYear()
    YearNum = Cells(1, 4)  ' Cell D1
    For MonthNum = 1 To 12
       Cells(2, MonthNum + 3).Value = DateSerial(YearNum, MonthNum, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want the date values to be a formula, so that the dates change if the user changes the year, change the line inside the `For Loop` to be:

```
Cells(2, MonthNum + 3).Formula = "=Date(R1C4," & MonthNum & ", 1)"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  I was thinking of looping, but I wasn't sure how I'd loop over the letters for each cell, using the index solves that.  I do have a question, does Excel start indexing at 1?  For instance, from my programming language knowledge, most indexes start at 0, and `Cells(1,4)` would actually be cell E2.  Additionally, there is a syntax error I'm sorting out.

Comment: The syntax error was the double right parenthesis inside the loop.  It is working correctly.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, Excel starts indexing at 1, not 0.  So cell A1 is `Cells(1,1)`. They probably did this because in the worksheet the rows are numbered starting at 1 and it would be too confusing if the rows were numbered one way in the sheet and a different way in the code.  Sorry about the syntax error, I've corrected that in my answer.